# Preventing parent page from refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created popup window in asp.net when i click on submit button of popup window my parent page get refresh. how i can prevent it to refresh. I have written code to refresh page on close event but not on submit but it get refresh on submit.

```
`function closeMe() {
            window.close();
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        window.opener.document.body.disabled = true;
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function () { myUnloadEvent(); }
    function myUnloadEvent() {
        window.opener.location.href = '../ContentPages/QuoteBuy.aspx';
    }`
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you open popup? Can you please share that code.

Answer (score 0):

**Submit** button always **send request to server**, so default it refresh the page.
To overcome this issue, you can define it as **simple button** Or you have below solutions in **Jquery Click event** code:

```
(1) return false; //at last statement of your code which not allow page to refresh
(2) use event.PreventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.onbeforeunload` gets triggered in case of `submit` too, so set `location.href` to refresh parent page just before `window.close()`.

```
function closeMe() {
        window.opener.location.href = '../ContentPages/QuoteBuy.aspx';
        window.close();
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        window.opener.document.body.disabled = true;
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function () { myUnloadEvent(); }
    function myUnloadEvent() {
        //Do your work
        //window.opener.location.href = '../ContentPages/QuoteBuy.aspx';
    }
```